# Unity3D like component system

Tags: c++, c++11, unity3d

I am currently working on my own little game engine and thought about implementing a simplified version of Unitys [component system](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) where you can attach objects of derived `Components` to an `GameObject`. Later you can request specific `Components` to use their functionality. Below is a stripped down (but still working) version of what I think about implementing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class GameObject;

class Component
{
private:
    GameObject * parent;

public:
    Component(GameObject * parent = nullptr)
    {
        this->parent = parent;
    }

    virtual ~Component() { parent = nullptr; }

    GameObject* GetParent() { return parent; }

    void SetParent(GameObject* parent) { this->parent = parent; }

    virtual std::string What() { return "Basic Component"; }
};

class SoundSource : public Component
{
private:
    // some sound specific members

public:
    SoundSource(GameObject * parent = nullptr) : Component(parent) {}

    virtual ~SoundSource() { }

    std::string What() { return "SoundSource Component"; }
};

class GameObject
{
private:
    std::vector<Component*> m_Components;

public:
    GameObject() :
        m_Components()
    {}

    ~GameObject()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Components.size(); ++i)
            if (m_Components[i]->GetParent() == this) delete m_Components[i];
        m_Components.clear();
    }


    void AddComponent(Component* comp)
    {
        if (comp->GetParent() == nullptr)
        {
            comp->SetParent(this);
        }
        m_Components.push_back(comp);
    }

    template <class component_type>
    component_type* GetComponent()
    {
        for (auto comp : m_Components)
        {
            component_type* c =  dynamic_cast<component_type*>(comp);
            if (c) return c;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    GameObject go;
    go.AddComponent(new SoundSource());
    go.AddComponent(new Component());

    SoundSource *s = go.GetComponent<SoundSource>();
    if (s) std::cout << s->What() << std::endl;
}
```

My initial plan for `GetComponent<>()` was to use the name of `typeid` to compare the component types, however since all components need to derive from the same base I think that using a `dynamic_cast` is the better option in this case. However I have never worked with dynamic casting before and I am not sure whether the way I use it is safe, so please tell me is it?

Also if you see any points for improvements I would appreciate your opinions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a C++ programmer, but there are a few things that I notice that I feel are important in any language.

#### Be Consistent:

While you'll find many people that are passionate about different naming conventions and coding styles, one thing that they'll all agree on is to *at least be consistent* in your choice. There are a few inconsistencies in your code:

- You declare a private member of your `Component` class named `parent`, and go on to introduce [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in your `GameObject` class with a member named `m_Components`.
- You declare a pointer with a space on either side of the asterisk: `Component * parent;` and go on with this style in your constructors, but you also connect the asterisk to the type in some other cases: `GameObject* GetParent()` and `SetParent(GameObject* parent)`.
- In your `GameObject` destructor, you have a `for` with a single-line body and choose to omit curly braces, but in it's `AddComponent` member function, you have an `if` with a single-line body but keep the curly-braces. If you're going to omit curly-braces in the former, you may as well omit them in the latter.
- If you insist on omitting the curly-braces, the former could also be written in a more readable manner:

  ```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Components.size(); ++i)
      if (m_Components[i]->GetParent() == this) 
          delete m_Components[i];
  ```

#### Also:

- `virtual std::string What() { return "Basic Component"; }` "What" is not a very descriptive identifier. Consider replacing it with something along the lines of "GetName()"
- The dynamic cast:

  ```
  component_type* c = dynamic_cast<component_type*>(comp);
      if (c) return c;
  ```

  I've often seen `dynamic_cast` in this form, which I find more readable:

  ```
  if (component_type* c = dynamic_cast<component_type*>(comp))
      return c;
  ```
- You use `std::vector` for your collection of Components. Any time where you loop through the elements of an `std::vector` in order to find a single element, you should consider using `std::map`. Using data structures like these to locate a Value object using a Key object will be **much** faster than looping through a `vector`, because *it will take the same amount of time regardless of how many items are in the collection*. This approach would result in a much faster GetComponent() method

I'm not sure if this is the approach used to implement `GetComponent` in Unity, but I know that it's advised against using `GetComponent` in the `Update` method in Unity because of how slow it is. If you used an `std::map` to implement your `GetComponent` method, it would be a marginal difference compared to doing the lookup in advance and storing the result (which is currently the recommended approach in Unity).

That's the only real feedback I have on your object-oriented design. For the most part, it seems like a pretty accurate C++ representation of Unity's component system.